# MySQL Where Query using string with special characters

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
`teams`
)
WHERE `name` = 'mi equiñerolico'
```

And the result of this query is:

```
idteam|name|datet
9|mi equiñerolíco|2012-06-23 12:15:32
```

As you can see it retrieves a row with the name 'mi equiñerolíco' even though that my Where clause establish that it must be 'mi equiñerolico'.

`teams` table has utf8_general_ci collation.

How can I solve this ambiguity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a binary collation to force an accent-sensitve compare:

```
select  * 
from    teams 
where   name = 'mi equiñerolico' collate utf8_bin
```